# How can I get the "Driver Educated" achievement?

Tags: achievements, valet-hero

Valet Hero has achievements for collecting all keys at each of the first five levels. I unlocked four of them, but I'm still missing the achievement for the very first one: Driver's Education.

Normally the achievement pops when I get 4 stars on the bronze, silver, and gold challenges. I have that (and 38 cars parked in marathon mode), so I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Is there anything I can do to get the achievement or is it permanently glitched?

Answer (score -1):

According to [GameFaqs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/iphone/986940-valet-hero/cheats) and [GameCenter](http://www.chaptercheats.com/cheat/iphone-ipod/103392/Valet-Hero/unlocks/23328/) you have to earn all keys on "Driver's Education"